# Why does does this CSS selector not work as I expected?

Tags: css, css-selectors

**Why does the following code not color "`Won`" red?** I would expect `#sisters>*~#too` to select all items who have an eventual sibling with `#too` (that is to say, all items before `#too`, i.e. `#won`). However, only `#too` is selected by `#sisters>*~#too`.

In short, **Why does `#sisters>*~#too` not select its preceding sibling, `#won`?**

```
<style>
#sisters>#too~*,
#sisters>*~#too {
    color: red;
}
</style>
<div id="sisters">
    <div id="won">Won</div>
    <div id="too">Too</div>
    <div id="tree">Tree</div>
    <div id="fore">Fore</div>
    <div id="jive">Jive</div>
</div>
```

SSCCE: http://jsfiddle.net/Supuhstar/XY4Dg/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't select elements in ascendant way on CSS. You can be able to select just descendant and after elements. So with this selector:

```
#sisters>*~#too
```

You are searching this way:

- All elements with id `too`

  - That are siblings `~`

    - Of any direct childrens `>*`

      - In a tag with `id sisters`

That way the CSS selectors always select the last item seted on the selector that meet all the previous conditions.

Answer (score 3):

The tilde, known as the General Sibling Combinator, selects any sibling after the element matched on the left side of it. There isn't a way of selecting a preceding element with *any* selector available today in CSS, unfortunately.